# Convert Non-partition table to partitioned table using ONLINE in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I got to know as we cannot convert existing non-partitioned table to partitioned table but the below link from the Oracle suggest that with the help of "ONLINE" keyword we can do it.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab ( a NUMBER(38,0), b NUMBER(38,0)); 

ALTER TABLE MY_TAB MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (a) INTERVAL (1000) (   
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)) ONLINE;
```

But it's not working for me, throwing error as "Invalid Partition Name".

I don't want to use `dbms_redefinition`.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? `select version 
from product_component_version
where product like 'Oracle%';` will tell you

Comment: Version : 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: It became available in 12c Release 2. You are using Release 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Oracle 12c Release 2` you could use single `ALTER` to convert non-partitioned table to partitioned one  :

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab ( a NUMBER(38,0), b NUMBER(38,0)); 

ALTER TABLE MY_TAB MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (a) INTERVAL (1000) (   
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)) ONLINE;
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0)` and without using `dbms_redefinition` your options may be limited to creating a new partitioned table with the same structure as the original table and copying over the data, creating indexes, constraints etc.

```
    CREATE TABLE my_tab_part -- new partitioned table
    PARTITION BY RANGE (a)
       INTERVAL ( 1000 )
       (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000))
    AS
       SELECT * FROM my_tab;
```